# Inconsistent chain after adding ProblemFactChange to Ssolution on real-time planning

Tags: java, optaplanner

I been working some time with optaplanner but is the first time I'm doing real-time planning, the problem is a pretty basic chained VRP with time windows, but right know I'm having an issue.

After working some time when I remove some `Standstill`'s with the documentation sequence (`ScoreDirector#beforeEntityRemoved`, removing the entity from the list and refresh the list instance, `ScoreDirector#afterEntityRemoved` and then `ScoreDirector#triggerVariableListeners`) from the chain, the chain becomes inconsistent, the previousStandStill's next standstill is not the same that the current standstill, and sometimes is even `null`

But all this happens only when I removed more than 2 or 3 `Standstill`s , if I remove only 1, it keeps working

PD: About removing the entity: I have tried with and without removing the entity reference from the current chain, but when I remove the element from the chain manually sometimes it shows an error telling me that the references are wrong but I don't understand why when I detect that the chain is inconsistent optaplanner doesn't detect it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < visitsToRemove.size(); i++) {
    OptimizingVisit visit = visitsToRemove.get( i );
    OptimizingVisit solverReference = scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject( visit );
    scoreDirector.beforeEntityRemoved( solverReference );
    solution.getVisits().remove( solverReference ); //working equals method is implemented here
    solution.setVisits( new ArrayList<>( solution.getVisits() ) );
    scoreDirector.afterEntityRemoved( solverReference );
    logger.info( String.format("Order #%s (%s) was removed from the solution",visit.getOrderNumber(),visit.getOrderId()) );
}
```

I know you guys could need more information and I will give it to you as needed, but I honestly don't know what is that you can need, my problem is pretty much a copy of the example with some ids for as reference to entities of my domain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In any case, the `solution.setVisits( new ArrayList<>( solution.getVisits() ) );` should be before the `for` loop and especially before the `solution.getVisits().remove( solverReference )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing a visit A from the visitList is not enough.
You also need to remove A from the chains. Any Visit B that has a `previous` reference pointing to A, must now point to A.previous. Any Visit C (=A.previous) for which C.next points to A, must now point to A.next (= B).

It's a PITA, yes. VRP simplification will make this a lot easier some day.

Comment: As a matter of fact I did this, before you answered me, I was about to edit my question, but is great having your answer on this question, thanks